# Performance comparison of FlexboxLayout with LinearLayout or RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-flexboxlayout

The immediate advantage I see is reduced `View` hierarchy but I couldn't help notice that it will need multiple passes during `onMeasure()`, in this scenario how does the performance of `FlexboxLayout` compare with `RelativeLayout` and others?

*Note: The official docs and GitHub wiki fail to mention performance improvements over other layouts at this time.*